# Continuar loop caso entrada seja 'S'

Tags: python, while

Tentei fazer um *loop*, que enquanto a entrada for 'S' ele volta e solicita de novo (é só pra eu aprender), caso a entrada for 'N' ele sai do *loop*, mas está em *loop* infinito.

```
continuar = input("Deseja continuar? ")

while continuar == 's':
    print("Você está continuando")
else:
    print("Você saiu")
```

Eu tentei utilizar o `break` porém ele interrompe o *loop* e para o programa.
Tentei utilizar também: `continuar += continuar`, mas acho que isso só funciona com números pelos testes que eu fiz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provavelmente quer que pergunte dentro do laço também, assim e está aceitando só entrando com minúscula, se quer maiúscula (conforme comentário) tem que fazer:

```
continuar = input("Deseja continuar? ")
while continuar == 'S':
    print("Você está continuando")
    continuar = input("Deseja continuar? ")
else:
    print("Você saiu")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/a20V4A). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ContinueLooppy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ContinueLoop.py).

Sem perguntar internamente a variável nunca mudará de valor no laço então não tem como sair, pedindo internamente uma hora é digitado um valor que deve sair e aí encerra.

Em geral não bem assim que deveria fazer, algo assim parece mais com algo real até porque não tem repetição de código, inclusive o ideia é aceitar qualquer caixa:

```
while True:
    continuar = input("Deseja continuar? ")
    if continuar != 'S' and continuar != 's':
        break
print("Encerrou")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8VBkzw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ContinueLoop2py). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ContinueLoop2.py).

Comment: Opa, ótimo, existe algum comando específico que eu possa fazer pra aceitar apenas letras minusculas ?

Comment: Coloque o `S´ maiúsculo, porque no momento só aceita minúsculo.

Comment: Agora fiquei de calça justa, o amigo de baixo tbm respondeu certo, posso marcar a dele como resposta certa pra ajudar ele na reputação também? Não sei como proceder :(

Comment: @Codador Pra obrigar a ser maisculo eu desconheço, mas, você pode usar o comando upper() pra transformar o valor digitado em maisculo. Ou, pode usar o comando lower() para transformar o valor digitado em minusculo.

Comment: @Codador Você deve marcar qual você acha melhor, você tem direito de escolher o que deseja, porém temos uma regra que não se deve votar na pessoa, nem por um motivo ou outro, o que deve ser determinado é o conteúdo. Qual te ajudou mais? Isto é o que deve definir, não a reputação atual da pessoa, seja baixa ou seja alta.

Comment: @Codador, se as duas respostas lhe ajudaram você pode votar nas duas como sendo úteis,[O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) , mas pode aceitar apenas uma resposta, [O que significa quando uma resposta é "aceita"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Lembrando que você também pode usar `if continuar not in ('s', 'S')`... nesse caso não faz diferença, mas o AP conhecer esta sintaxe facilita para casos com mais critérios de teste.

Comment: A ta, beleza, pessoal obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

O loop infinito está acontecendo por conta de você não alterar ou solicitar um novo valor para a variável `continuar`, com isso uma vez que o valor seja `'s'` ele nunca será alterado e o loop torna-se infinito.

Você pode corrigir isso de forma simples, colocando o input dentro do loop, solicitando assim uma nova entrada de dados, dando ao usuário de sair do loop.

Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo:

```
continuar = input("Deseja continuar? ")

while continuar == 's':
    print("Você está continuando")
    continuar = input("Deseja continuar? ")
else:
    print("Você saiu")
```

Aqui o exemplo executável na web: https://repl.it/repls/NoteworthySupportiveConsulting

Comment: Opa, ótimo, existe algum comando específico que eu possa fazer pra aceitar apenas letras minusculas ?

Answer (score 2):

O que você quer pode ser resolvido utilizando o seguinte algritmo:

```
while True:
    print('Você está continuando!')

    # Capturando e avaliando a resposta.
    resp = input('Desejas continuar? [S/N]').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('\033[31mDigite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input('Desejas continuar? [S/N]').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Agora, para mostrar a **lógica** deste algoritmo funcionando é bom utilizarmos um **caso real**.

Pois bem, imagine que tenhamos o seguinte caso real: Insira `valores inteiros` em uma lista até o momento que desejar parar. No momento que desejar parar, digite a letra `N` para que a lista montada até o momento seja exibida e **encerre** a execução do script.

Neste caso podemos utilizar o seguinte script:

```
cont = 0
numeros = list()
while True:
    cont += 1

    # Verifica a palavra mais apropriada para solicitação dos valores.
    if cont == 1:
        msg = 'algum'
    else:
        msg = 'outro'

    # Solicita uma resposta "S" ou "N" para continuar ou encerrar a execução do laço.
    resp = input(f'Desejas inserir {msg} número? [S/N]? ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('\033[31mDigite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input(f'Desejas inserir {msg} número? [S/N]? ').upper()

    # Caso a resposta seja "S" iremos adicionar um valor à lista.
    if resp == 'S':
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {cont}º valor: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        numeros.append(valor)

    # Caso a resposta seja "N" o script exibe a lista e encerra sua execução.
    else:
        print(f'\033[32mA lista gerada foi:\n{numeros}\033[m')
        break
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/fjcgxiaq-solkarped) o funcionamento do script.

Observe que quando executamos este script recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Desejas inserir algum número? [S/N]?`. Neste momento - se desejamos de fato inserir algum número - devemos pressionar `"S"`. Em seguida recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Digite o 1º valor:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o valor e pressionar `enter`. A partir de então, o script verificará se o valor digitado é `inteiro`. Caso positivo, o referido valor será adicionado à lista `numeros`. Caso contrário, será levantada uma exceção até que o usuário digite um valor `inteiro`.

Posteriormente o script será reexecutado nos exibindo a seguinte mensagem: `Desejas inserir outro número? [S/N]?`. Se neste momento digitarmos `"S"`, o processo de solicitação do valor e, consequentemente, sua inserção na lista `numeros` será refeito. Caso digitarmos `"N"`, o script mostrará a lista contendo todos os valores digitados até o momento e **encerrará** a execução do script.